# Dispatch 100 HTTP Request in order

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using objective-C to write an app which needs to dispatch 100 web request and the response will be handled in the call back. My question is, how can I execute web req0, wait for call back, then execute web req1 and so on?

Thanks for any tips and help.

```
                        NSURL *imageURL = [[contact photoLink] URL];
                        GDataServiceGoogleContact *service = [self contactService];

                        // requestForURL:ETag:httpMethod: sets the user agent header of the
                        // request and, when using ClientLogin, adds the authorization header
                        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [service requestForURL:imageURL
                                                                         ETag: nil
                                                                   httpMethod:nil];

                        [request setValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

                        GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];

                        fetcher.retryEnabled = YES;
                        fetcher.maxRetryInterval = 0.3;
                        fetcher.minRetryInterval = 0.3;
                        [fetcher setAuthorizer:[service authorizer]];
                        [fetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self
                                      didFinishSelector:@selector(imageFetcher:finishedWithData:error:)];
                    }


- (void)imageFetcher:(GTMHTTPFetcher *)fetcher finishedWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError *)error {

    if (error == nil) {
        // got the data; display it in the image view.  Because this is sample
        // code, we won't be rigorous about verifying that the selected contact hasn't
        // changed between when the fetch began and now.
       // NSImage *image = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];

       // [mContactImageView setImage:image];

        NSLog(@"successfully fetched the data");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"imageFetcher:%@ failedWithError:%@", fetcher,  error);
    }
}
```

Comment: How have you tried doing it so far? What went wrong?

Comment: I am frustrated, all my req are issued even before the first call back kicks in

Comment: Show the code and explain the issue

Comment: just added the code, can you please help me

Comment: Where are the 100 requests in that code?

Comment: I didn't show the for loops, the fetcher is executed 100 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply call this code in a loop as `GTMHTTPFetcher` works asynchronously so the loop, as you see, will iterate and start all instances without any delay.

A simple option is to put all of the `contact`s into a mutable array, take the first `contact` from the array (remove it from the array) and start the first fetcher. Then, in the `finishedWithData` callback, check if the array contains anything, if it does remove the first item and start a fetch with it. In this way the fetches will run serially one after the other.

A better but more complex solution would be to create an asynchronous `NSOperation` (there are various guides on the web) which starts a fetch and waits for the callback before completing. The benefit of this approach is that you can create all of your operations and add them to an operation queue, then you can set the max concurrent count and run the queue - so you can run multiple fetch instances at the same time. You can also suspend the queue or cancel the operations if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I was thinking about the simple solution you brought up. But worries that call the fetch again in the call back function seems weird, what do you think? Or is that quite common to so so? Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't say it's common or weird, just one solution to your situation. It isn't a recursive call as such because it's asynchronous. You will still only have 1 fetch running at a time.